# How can I do double buffering in SDL 2.0?

Tags: sdl-2

I have a tile tile map array [50][50].

When I click the mouse to move the x and y of every single tile in that array I see white spaces between each tile - I believe this is called 'tearing', it isn't desired.

I googled double buffering and read the wiki, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics .

How is it done in SDL2, specifically with large tile arrays created from 'for loops'?

...I suspect you copy tile textures onto a buffer texture and copy that to the renderer once its fully loaded - though I couldn't get this to work, would love to see a full working example!

This is my previous post with current my current code:
[SDL2 double buffer not working, still tearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334892/sdl2-double-buffer-not-working-still-tearing)

Comment: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip

Comment: @Vality That's SDL1.

Comment: @zenith Sorry, wrong docs. Its replaced by http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent which does the same thing

Comment: It *might* be tearing, or it might not be. It's simply not possible to say without seeing what you mean. It might just be other problems with the drawing?

Comment: @OP Double buffering is built in to the SDL2 rendering mechanism, e.g. `SDL_RenderPresent` will flip the front/back buffer with each call. You don't need to do anything special about it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I think your issue may actually be to do with vsync, not with double buffering

Answer (score 6):

SDL2 handles double buffering automatically for you:

- `SDL_RenderClear` will clear the current rendering buffer.
- `SDL_RenderCopy` will render textures to the current rendering buffer.
- `SDL_RenderPresent` will swap the buffers, showing everything that was rendered using `SDL_RenderCopy` since the last `SDL_RenderClear` call.

Comment: If the buffers are just being swapped, then you don't need vsync, right?

Comment: [Wrong](https://hardforum.com/threads/how-vsync-works-and-why-people-loathe-it.928593/). (ctrl-f for "double-buffering")

Comment: I thought switching buffers would have been as simple as a pointer move.

Answer (score 2):

As of SDL2 all hardware rendering has to be double buffered, so you need make sure firstly that you are doing all your drawing through [the hardware rendering library](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender).

Then you simply need to call [`SDL_RenderPresent`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent) in order to flip the double buffer.

If you currently using the [software rendering system](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategorySurface) this should fix it. However if you are already doing this I would suspect some other issue is at hand, you may want to check if you are using vsync and see if there are other bugs in your drawing code that could cause this.

Note that if you are not currently using vsync this is also a likely cause.
You will need to fix this by setting the [SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC) hint.

Comment: Tried add vsync to the renderer, no change. I suspect it's in the drawing code - i shal double check that. Thanks!